# Как проверить,что сслово начинается и заканчивается на одну букву? c++

Tags: c++

Допустим у нас есть набор слов, который записан в одномерный массив.

```
std::ofstream file;
    file.open("D:\\Лаба\\text1.txt");
    int m;
    cout << "Введите кол-во слов = ";
    cin >> m;
    string* words = new string[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите " << i + 1 << " слово: ";
        cin >> words[i];
        file << words[i]<<endl;
    }
```

Как найти слово, начинающееся и заканчивающееся на одну букву?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил с помощью итераторов. Это конечно более громоздко чем просто обратиться по индексу, но пусть будет и такой вариант. Сам код:

```
if(*words[i].begin()==*(--words[i].end())){
        std::cout << "EQUAL" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: А с русским текстом что будете делать?

Comment: Можно использовать `front/back` вместо `begin/--end`, также неплохо было бы проверку на длину добавить, что-то вроде `if (!words[i].empty() && words[i].front() == words[i].back())`

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно добавить создать функцию для проверки суть которой будет следующая

```
if(word[0] == word[word.size()-1]){
return true;
}
return false;
```